# Play a sound while using try and catch

Tags: java, file-io, try-catch, fileinputstream

Unable to compile. I am  trying to play a sound while using try and catch. The wav file is located on my desktop.
I am  getting errors such as:
    AudioStream cannot be resolved to a type
    AudioStream cannot be resolved to a type
    AudioPlayer cannot be resolved.

I am unsure how to fix this i know its something simple,

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class PlayMySoundApplication
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
 throws Exception
{
// open the sound file as a Java input stream
String applause2x = "/Users/pc/Desktop/applause2x.wav";
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(applause2x);

// create an audiostream from the inputstream
AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);

// play the audio clip with the audioplayer class
AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
```

Comment: 1. try & catch is for handling exceptions. 2. i cannot see your try & catch in your posted code

Comment: 3. You haven't imported `AudioStream` nor `AudioPlayer`

Comment: In the case of the code above, the `throws Exception` statement should act as an action listener.

Comment: @JonathanArendt the throws Exception should be replaced by a try-catch

Comment: Agreed, however what's causing the issue? Lack of importing the `AudioPlayer` and `AudioStream` classes?

Comment: throws Exception does not have anything to do with ActionListener. And there is no obvious need to replace it with a try-catch at all. Only catch exceptions if you can handle them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what sound library you are trying to use.

If you are using a decent version of the JDK, that should do the trick :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class MakeSound {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LineUnavailableException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException {
        playSound("test.wav");
    }

    public static void playSound(String strFilename)
            throws LineUnavailableException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException {

        File soundFile = new File(strFilename);

        AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);

        AudioFormat audioFormat = audioStream.getFormat();

        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
        try (SourceDataLine sourceLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);) {
            sourceLine.open(audioFormat);
            sourceLine.start();

            int nBytesRead = 0;
            byte[] abData = new byte[128000];
            while (nBytesRead != -1) {
                nBytesRead = audioStream.read(abData, 0, abData.length);
                if (nBytesRead > 0) {
                    sourceLine.write(abData, 0, nBytesRead);
                }
            }

            sourceLine.drain();
        }
    }
}
```

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

Add imports for audio,

```
import java.io.*;
import sun.audio.*;


public class PlayMySoundApplication
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  throws Exception
  {
    // open the sound file as a Java input stream
    String applause2x = "/Users/pc/Desktop/applause2x.wav";
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(applause2x);


    // create an audiostream from the inputstream
    AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);

    // play the audio clip with the audioplayer class
    AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
  }
}
```